# scala range returns Long instead of Int

Tags: scala, types

I have the following code to print the numbers from 1 to 9 in letters

```
class IntToNumber(num:Int) {
    val digits = Map("1" -> "one", "2" -> "two", "3" -> "three", "4" -> "four", "5" -> "five", "6"  -> "six", "7" -> "seven", "8" -> "eight", "9" -> "nine")
    def inLetters():String = {
        digits.getOrElse(num.toString,"")
    }
}

implicit def intWrapper(num:Int) = new IntToNumber(num)
(1 until 10).foreach(n => println(n.inLetters))
```

When I run this code I get an error saying the method is not available for Long

```
Script.scala:9: error: value inLetters is not a member of Long
(1 until 10).foreach(n => println(n.inLetters))
                                    ^
one error found
```

Changing the last line to

```
(1 until 10).foreach(n => println(n.toInt.inLetters))
```

Works fine..

Can someone help me understand Why is that (1 until 10) range returning Long and not int?

Comment: Puzzling. `(1 until 10) : IndexedSeq[Int]` says the expression has type `NumericRange.Exclusive[Long]` and so ascription is invalid. `(1 until 10) : IndexedSeq[Long]` works.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Executing `(1 until 2) foreach (x => println(x.getClass))` does not give consistent results. Sometimes it prints `int`, some other times it prints `long`.

Comment: Oh, looks like @ziggystar solved the mystery. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've changed the name of your implicit conversion to `intWrapperX`. The following session shows the fixed example.

The problem is, that your `intWrapper` shadows `scala.Predef.intWrapper(i:Int): RichInt` which is needed to create the `Range` object. I leave the explanation of why the conversion to `Long` (or presumable `RichLong`) kicks in to the commenters.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class IntToNumber(num:Int) {
    val digits = Map("1" -> "one", "2" -> "two", "3" -> "three", "4" -> "four", "5" -> "five", "6"  -> "six", "7" -> "seven", "8" -> "eight", "9" -> "nine")
    def inLetters():String = {
        digits.getOrElse(num.toString,"")
    }
}

implicit def intWrapperX(num:Int) = new IntToNumber(num)    

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class IntToNumber
intWrapperX: (num: Int)IntToNumber

scala> (1 until 10).foreach(n => println(n.inLetters))
one
two
three
...
```

Comment: I wish SO had told me about your answer sooner. It let me spend 13 minutes figuring it out for myself, then halfway through typing up my answer it told me about this one :(

Comment: In case anyone's interested, the `Long` is probably generated by the 'NumericRange`, which deals with stuff like `1L to 10L` or `'a' to 'z'`. I have no idea how it got there, though.